# Windows Batch Code references

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to understand / learn what each of these code references equal.  Can someone point me to a good place to read up on this.  I am assuming its windows powershell code .. but I am just guessing.

For example what does - %%a represet

```
@echo off
rem For each file in your folder
for %%a in (".\*") do (
    rem check if the file has an extension and if it is not our script
    if "%%~xa" NEQ ""  if "%%~dpxa" NEQ "%~dpx0" (
        rem check if extension forlder exists, if not it is created
        if not exist "%%~xa" mkdir "%%~xa"
        rem Copy (or change to move) the file to directory
        copy "%%a" "%%~dpa%%~xa\"
    )
)
```

Comment: http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html or you can type `for /?`

Comment: Thank you both very much

Comment: Check out the [tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/batch-file/info) for tag [tag:batch-file] -- you will find a lot of useful links providing `cmd`/batch coding references...

Comment: user6017774 bad link

Answer (score 0):

Here %%a provide the each file name For loop is iterating and %~xa gives the file extension. This is what I know right now. any details would be great.

Answer (score -1):

I guess, this program grouping files according their extensions. Then open directories with founded extensions. After then moving the files to each directory accordingly..